# Autologin fail

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, chat, login

It looks like the auto-login feature doesn't work for me (on Firefox 3.6.9).
I've just had to re-sign into each site individually.

Also, chat is giving weird messages and inverting the order of the messages (probably related), like so:

> Why did my last comment supercede the
>   first one? - parsererror - retry /
>   cancel
>
> What is that verbiage that just
>   followed my last comment after fail
>   about? - parsererror - retry / cancel
>
> Looks like auto-login is a fail. -
>   parsererror - retry / cancel

Here's a pic of a site not having me logged in, after signing into five other sites and hitting the 'Questions' button.

[image]

Comment: `"It looks like the auto-login fail doesn't work worth crap"`.... so that means it works right?

Comment: @peter, hehe, that's one way to interpret that.  It's the best I could do as frustrated as I am.

Comment: @Michael, Thanks, it's good to see a cool head do some good editing.

Comment: Why do you think these two problems are related, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Michael, There was a message stating that there was a problem connecting to the server, and this was happening while I was doing the sign-ons.  Once I refreshed the pages, they worked normal (and my messages disappeared).

Answer (score 2):

From the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/):

> But please be advised that we may not
> be able to automatically log in you
> in, if …
>
> - You’ve been to the target site
>   recently without a global auth session
>   (click the “login” link at the top of
>   every page to force it)
> - ...

Clicking "Questions" will not force an auto login.

---

That aside, looking at the logs it does not appear you were ever successfully getting a StackAuth session.  This could be for any number of reasons: bad javascript in your browser cache (despite cache breakers, I've seen a couple cases of this with various javascript in the last month), flaky DNS (StackAuth's DNS record was smashed a few days ago, you may still have a bad copy), or there's some proxy/anonymizer* between you and us.

Also, chat and global login share no code.  Aside from indicating something kind of goofy with your browser at the time, the issues would be unrelated.

Ultimately, I cannot reproduce this.  If you can come up with reproduction steps I'll gladly take another look, but until then this is [status-norepro].

<sub>*Anything that smashes your [HTTP Referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) or causes your IP to change between requests would do it for sure.</sub>

Comment: one thing I find is that I whilst I get auto-logged in, the status banner across the top of the page still shows the "Log in" link instead of my display name and rep. This may be confusing people, it certainly caught me out. This happens in Chrome 5 and 6 for me.

Comment: @Kev - we can't do anything about it until we know if you've got a global login session, and when we *do* know we push down that notice immediately.  I guess we could hide login while we're "loading"... but that might be a bit rough on anonymous users (who make up the bulk of our traffic).  Hmmm...  I'll think on this.

Comment: just so you know the sequence - 1. Browse to site, 2. The auto-login notification drops down to tell me "Welcome back Kev, you've been logged on...". 3. If I click the "Click here to refresh" link all is good. But if I click "Close This Window" that's when it can get confusing and that's the link my eye is always drawn to.

Comment: it's not that they share code, it probably has to do with chat working off of the Meta login.